# On which site can I ask questions about product suggestions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for RFID readers and antennas which work within 915 - 917 MHz according to Israel regulations. I have searched a lot, but found nothing.

On which site should I post this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) is your friend. :-)

This site is *only* for questions where you have a list of requirements, and you are looking for a hardware matching the best this list. Beware - a single close vote is enough there for a closure.

Your list will be this:

- RFID reader and antenna
- works within 915-917 MHz
- matches .il law

Good luck.

Comment: + plugs into a computer I suspect. I don't think we do non computer hardware recs IIRC

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Probably yes. Although today everything plugs into a computer (maybe by some adapters).